# Minecraft - Info bar above inventory bar completely artifacted

Tags: java, rendering, minecraft, minecraft-forge, visual-artifacts

I have isolated the issue in the following line of code:

```
Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj.drawStringWithShadow(etc)
```

I'm extremely confused as to why it's artifacting the xp bar, health bar, food bar and armour bar. Here's a portion of my code:

```
// the main code
public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new MyMod());
}

// MyMod class
public uiCreator;
public MyMod() {
    uiCreator = new UICreator();
}

@SubscribeEvent
public void onGui(RenderGameOverlayEvent event) {
    uiCreator.Create();
}

// UICreator class
public void Create() {
    GlStateManager.scale(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj.drawStringWithShadow("MyMod", 2, 2, 0xffffff);
    GlStateManager.scale(1 / 1.5, 1 / 1.5, 1 / 1.5);
}
```

Effectively, the line which is causing the artifacting is `Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj.drawStringWithShadow("MyMod", 2, 2, 0xffffff);`. I don't understand why. I'm certain it's this line, as removing/commenting out any other portions of code do not fix the artifacting until I comment this line out. I'm extremely confused as to why this is occuring. If anyone has any form of insight, I'd greatly appreciate it

[image: Artifacting Info Bar]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as follows:

When you attempt to drawString, it replaces the textures with a text texture. Due to this, anything rendered afterwards ends up looking like text instead of proper icons because the texture was replaced in Memory. In order to avoid this, use `RenderGameOverlayEvent.Post` and check if `event` is getting the type of TEXT render.